# Настройка почтового ящика для отправки писем

Tags: php

Создал функцию `send_mail()`, которая генерирует и отправляет забытый пароль от сайта.

Как настроить почту, с которой будет отправляться пароль для пользователя?

```
send_mail('почта которую нужно настроить', $email,
        'Новый пароль для сайта blabla.ru', 'Ваш пароль: ' . $newpass);
```

Comment: _настроить почту_ - это что с ней сделать надо?

Comment: Как и что сделать чтобы отправлялся пароль через ту почту которую введу. `send_mail('no-reply@blabla.ru', $email,
        'Новый пароль для сайта blabla.ru', 'Ваш пароль: ' . $newpass);`

Comment: Что за сервер? А то создаешь пользователя и указываешь, что от имени этого пользователя может посылать такой-то IP (для Exchange Server могу дать детали конфигурации) без всякой авторизации. А если проблема в инициации отправки письма, настраивать надо пхп-мэйлер, указывая ему IP сервера.

Comment: Например: Есть email с которого надо отправить по функции письмо пользователю который запросит пароль своей учетки и так у нас есть функция: `function send_mail($from,$to,$subject,$body)
 {
  $charset = 'utf-8';
  mb_language("ru");
  $headers = "MIME Version: 1.0 \n";
  $headers = "From: <".$from."> \n";
  $headers = "Reply-To: <".$to." \n>";
  $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=$charset \n";
  $subject = '=?'.$charset.'?B'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';

  mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
 } `

Answer (score 1):

в общем случае — настройка не требуется.

вы можете писать в обратном адресе любой синтаксически верный адрес (например, `obama@whitehouse.gov`). и ваше письмо (если установлен какой-нибудь [mta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)) будет отправлено.

вот только с огромной вероятностью оно не дойдёт до почтового ящика адресата, т.к. будет расценено как спам.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendmailer($to,$from,$subject,$msg){
$s="=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($subject)."?="; 
$headers="MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n"."Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n"."From: ".$from."\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n"."Return-Path: ".$from."\r\n"."X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n"."Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
if($sendPass=mail($to,$s,$msg,$headers)) return true; else return false;
}
```

А через СМТП как будеть?